# Copy TextBox text to clipboard on Button click without code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I recall correctly it is possible, but I cannot find it.

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button`. If you click on it, it should copy everything from `TextBox` to clipboard.

```xml
<Button
   Name="BtnCopyToClipboard"
   Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
   Content="Copy"/>
```

I have something like this, but `Button` is greyed out, Why?

Comment: While the accepted answer mentions it, the short answer is that `ApplicationCommands.Copy` behaves just like Microsoft Word: **Copy button is disabled when there is no selected text.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by specifying the `TextBox` as [`CommandTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandtarget?view=net-5.0).

> Gets or sets the element on which to raise the specified command.

You can bind the `TextBox` using the `ElementName` binding syntax.

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"/>
   <Button
      Name="BtnCopyToClipboard"
      Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
      CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox}"
      Content="Copy"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Please note that this will only copy the *selected* text. If you want to copy all text regardless of the selection to the clipboard, you will need to use an event handler in code-behind or write a custom attached behavior.

```
<Button 
   x:Name="BtnCopyToClipboard"
   Click="CopyAllTextToClipboard"
   Content="Copy"/>
```

```
private void CopyAllTextToClipboard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Clipboard.SetText(MyTextBox.Text);
}
```

Yet another approach is to override the default command binding for the `Copy` command. This offers the advantage to specify a can execute handler that enables and disables the button.

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox">
      <TextBox.CommandBindings>
         <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" Executed="Copy_Executed" CanExecute="Copy_CanExecute"/>
      </TextBox.CommandBindings>
   </TextBox>
   <Button
      Name="BtnCopyToClipboard"
      Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
      CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox}"
      Content="Copy"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
private void Copy_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   e.CanExecute = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextBox.Text);
}

private void Copy_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Clipboard.SetText(MyTextBox.Text);
}
```